# What is the character for resistance?

Tags: english-to-japanese

What is the character for the word resistance. I'm looking for the term in the sense of "I feel resistance towards taking on this challenge".

Answer (score 6):

In that context, you really do not have many choices.  It would be either 「[抵抗]{ていこう}」 or 「抵抗[感]{かん}」.

> "I feel resistance towards taking on this challenge."

could be said as:

> 「この[挑戦]{ちょうせん}を[受]{う}けるのは抵抗がある。」
>
> 「この挑戦を受けることには抵抗感がある。」
>
> 「この挑戦を受けることには抵抗感を感じる。」

Comment: Is there a single (or just a couple characters) for just "resistance"  that would make sense?

Comment: @KyleBrandt the word he's giving you -- *teikou* ([抵抗]{ていこう}) fits exactly that.